# Call to member function execute eval'd

Tags: php, eval

So, i'm getting this really weird error when i attempt to run my code. I'm attempting to put this into a IPB Widget.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on string in http://home/rmjeng/public_html/redacted.net/forum/plugins/phptxtwidget/widgets/sodPhpWidget.php(106) : eval()'d code on line 12
```

my code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value = "Check Donor Status" name="SubmitButton"/>
<?php
include("system/Login/Steam.php");
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){



$uid = $member->steamid;
$sql = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=donation_system;charset=utf8', 'donation', 'redacted');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `transactions` WHERE  `uid` = :trans";
$sql->execute(array(':trans' => $uid));
$result = $sql->fetchObject();
if ($result->total > 0)
{
// lets assign the IPB Rank
$dbh2 = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=voxel_ipboard;charset=utf8', 'ipboard_user', 'redacted');

$count = $dbh2->exec("UPDATE  `voxel_ipboard`.`core_members` SET `member_group_id` =  '2' WHERE  `core_members`.`steamid` =:trans;");

echo "assigned donator rank";
header('Location: http://www.voxelservers.net/forum');



}
}
?>
```